How can I find out right away when new tokens are made on TON (Telegram Open Network)?
I'm looking to quickly get updates about newly minted tokens on the TON blockchain. How can I achieve this with minimal delay?
For example, within 30 seconds, I want to receive details like the token's address, total supply, associated image, and the creator's address.
The programming language isn't a big concern; I'm more interested in the approach. Appreciate any help!
I've experimented with tools like BitQuerry and GetBlock, but I'm still struggling to figure it out. It's possible I haven't dedicated enough time to it, or perhaps I'm focusing on the wrong aspects.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
